# WildFly use specified port

Tags: jboss, wildfly

How can I specify a port in WildFly? For example I want to use the port `4888` or `8695`.

Here's my `standalone.xml` file. So far I use `Port+100` as you can see.

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Thanks

Comment: For what do you want to use 4888 or 8695?

Comment: That was a example...whatever - i want to know how can i specify a Port(not a range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change the configuration using the CLI like this:

```
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=management-http:write-attribute(name=port, value=19990)
```

Or you can pass the desired value from the command-line when starting WildFly:

```
./standalone.sh -Djboss.management.http.port=19990
```